# How to call WP3.5 Media Library manager?

Tags: uploads, gallery, media, media-library

In the past Media Library window could be called like this:

```
tb_show("Upload image", "media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=520");
```

This still works in WP3.5. But I'm wondering how to open a new media manager? It's no longer handled by Thickbox - `tb_show()`.

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the article [How to use WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader in Theme Options](http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/) *(by codestag.com)*, as seen in [Using the WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader within plugins](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) *(by mikejolley.com)*. <sup>*Mike Jolley's article has quite some nice tricks.*</sup>

***Important note***: if the page where the uploader is going to be used ***doesn't already have*** all media JS APIs, then [`wp_enqueue_media()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_media/) has to be called.

---

So, supposing we have a button like this in a custom Meta Box:

```
<div class="uploader">
      <input type="text" name="settings[_wpse_82857]" id="_wpse_82857" />
      <input class="button" name="_wpse_82857_button" id="_wpse_82857_button" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

The following script will call the new uploader and fill up the input text field `#_wpse_82857` with the attachment path when <kbd>Insert into post</kbd> is clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var _custom_media = true,
        _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

    // ADJUST THIS to match the correct button
    $('.uploader .button').click(function(e) 
    {
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        var button = $(this);
        var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
        _custom_media = true;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment)
        {
            if ( _custom_media ) 
            {
                $("#"+id).val(attachment.url);
            } else {
                return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
            };
        }

        wp.media.editor.open(button);
        return false;
    });

    $('.add_media').on('click', function()
    {
        _custom_media = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this work on admin side?

Comment: great example . +1 . but is there a reason why this does not work with the array-like formatting of `id="settings[_wpse_82857]"`

Comment: I'm getting the following error in console: ReferenceError: wp is not defined.  Can you please help me if you know what it is?

Comment: You are really great.